# Android into local network to query the MS SQL Server

Tags: android, sql-server, local-network

There are several sources where described how to share folder between android device and PC in a local network and I'm just wondering, is it possible to query a local MS SQL Server from the android device by placing it into the local network?

I tried to use a WiFi to establish a local network with PC which are sharing the same router, but so far PC and phone do not see each other. If I'll finally will succeeded to place them into the same local network, will be it possible to query my MS SQL server or probably I'm missing something and will fail at the end?

Comment: [Connect2SQL](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.jromero.connect2sql.donate&hl=en)

Comment: So, actually the main problem now is to establish the connection between android device and PC inside the local network to push them to be accessible for each other, and if this tool could execute quires to MS SQL Server, so it shouldn't be a big deal to manage how to do it without this tool.

Comment: You need a client to query SQL Server. The client uses libraries to interface with SQL Server. That tool is an example of a client. Once you establish a connection between an android device and a PC what are you going to use to submit queries to the database engine?